# siunitx in table: unexpected spacing

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\numtablerange[1][]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\numtable@range{#1}}{\numtable@range{#1}[#1]}}
  \def\numtable@range#1[#2]#3#4{%
    \numtablerange@boxme{\expandafter\tablenum\expandafter[\numtablerange@lopt,#1]{#3}}--%
    \numtablerange@boxme{\expandafter\tablenum\expandafter[\numtablerange@ropt,#2]{#4}}%
  }
\newcolumntype{T}[3]{>{\def\numtablerange@lopt{#1}\def\numtablerange@ropt{#2}}#3}
\newcommand*\numtablerange@boxme[1]{{\sbox0{#1}\usebox0}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{
    T{table-format = 2.2, output-decimal-marker = {:}}
     {table-format = 2.2, output-decimal-marker = {:}}
     {c}
  }
   \toprule
    {Tidsrum}                    \\
   \midrule
    \numtablerange{ 9.00}{10.00} \\
    \numtablerange{10.00}{11.00} \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

Years ago I compiled some code (of which the example above is a snip) which didn't result in the space after the colon, as far as I remember. I cannot figure out why it is there.

How do I remove the space after the colon?

**Thought**

I think it might be do to something introduced in [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) v3 but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Your thought may be correct, at least with `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` you don't get the space.

Comment: You want `output-decimal-marker = \mathord{:}` - bit short of time this evening, will write a full answer tomorrow

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you, Joseph. Can you maybe explain why my code worked as expected in v2 but not in v3?

Comment: @josephwright I experimented briefly with this earlier today and found that `{:}` which should be equivalent to `\mathord{:}` didn’t work.

Comment: @DonHosek See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend explicitly marking up where you want tokens to be treated as `\mathord`: `output-decimal-marker = \mathord{:}`. This will work in both v2 and v3, and has the advantage that it retains the semantic information which using simply `{...}` does not. That is useful for example when switching to text mode, where `{...}` has no special meaning and where appropriate replacement of `\mathord` by a text mode equivalent can be used to retain important information.

The reason you see a change is rather technical, and will only show in tabular alignment. In v2, table cells were constructed by formatting each part of the number separately. This was rather slow and meant that there was a need to do this separately from 'normal' numbers, leading to some edge case bugs. For v3, I have picked up an idea from `pgfplotstable`: format using a marker between each part for alignment. For a normal number, the marker is empty and nothing is different. For an alignment, the marker is used to split out the various parts of the number, meaning alignment is faster and not using a different formatting path.

The issue arises as TeX removes braces if we match the entirety of a delimited argument in one go:

```
\def\foo#1X#2X#3\stop{\showtokens{#2}}
\foo stuffX{content}X\stop
\foo stuffX{content} X\stop
```

That means that a single extra set of braces around an entire numerical part will be dropped: usually not an issue but a problem if you are using `{X}` not `\mathord{X}` to make a symbol mathord. I could change the table setup to avoid this, but then I'd be back to a slower setup (there are *lots* of parts of a number I'd have to cover).

If you don't want to use `\mathord`, you can use an additional set of braces, which will deal with the issue. Or you could say add some space inside braces, which would be ignored in math mode but which would also prevent brace stripping.

Comment: I've logged an issue as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/527: I think I can handle decimals separately from other parts, which would deal with the issue but keep the general performance uplift.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's something I do not understand in your code, but why not this simple code?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{ output-decimal-marker = \mathord{:}, range-phrase=\,--}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
   \toprule
    {Tidsrum} \\
   \midrule
    \hphantom{0}\numrange{9.00}{10.00} \\
    \numrange{10.00}{11.00} \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like not to have a `0` in front of `9:00`. (I also have the entry `8:00--9:00`, if that is of any importance.)

Comment: I did that to centre the endash used as the range-symbol. I didn't see  how to do it without adding a $0$ if the hour number has only one digit, and as it is a standard formatting for time, I used it. I tried first `\phantom{0}`, but it produced an error message. Perhaps looking more deeply in the manual of  version 3, there is a solution, but I don't have time at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Bernard. I hope that Joseph will see the post and reply with a "proper" fix to the `siunitx` package.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Maybe it's me who didn't look  at the details in the manual. I'll have some more time tomorrow, and if I find a solution, of course, I'll update.

Comment: Thanks alot. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Finally, one just had to put the `\hphantom{0}` outside `\numrange`. Looks like a dirty hack, but it's simple…